# How can I add a value from one array to a new empty associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array

I want to count how many times a number exists in my array, but I want to do it like this.

I have an empty array like this:

```
$aNumberArray = array();
```

And I have an array like this:

```
$aArray = (4,4,5,7,4,8,7,9,4,3);
```

This is my code so far:

```
foreach ($aArray as $value) {
if (in_array($value, $aNumberArray)) {
// increase value in $aNumerArray.
}else{
// add $value from $aArray to $aNumberArray as key and as value add 1.
}
}
```

I want to know how I can add the value from $aArray to $aNumberArray as a key and I want to add number 1 as value. When It excist it most increase the value from $aArray.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
$aNumberArray = array();
$aArray = array(4,4,5,7,4,8,7,9,4,3);
foreach ($aArray as $value) {
    if (!isset($aNumberArray[$value])) {
        $aNumberArray[$value] = 0;
    }
    $aNumberArray[$value] += 1;
}
print_r($aNumberArray);
```

Will give you:

```
Array
(
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 1
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check output of it

```
$aArray = [4,4,5,7,4,8,7,9,4,3]; // correct this array format
print_r(array_count_values($aArray));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 1
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c9a3dd993f6f36a7993bb92d4e61905c10c36331)

[array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) — Counts all the values of an array